# How to make JBoss server bundled to your Web Application?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss

The idea is to embed jboss AS7 to my project and add it to version control. Additionally to check the ability of start the server using mvn jboss:devserver  (similar to how we run mvn appengine:devserver)   So does it makes sense to write my own archtype ?

To my client this reduce lot of complexities so we can create our own jboss configuration to work with and the client's C# developers who will be going to work on java project development. find it easier to setup their local machines to run their changes locally. using similar command mentioned above.(mvn jboss:devserver) I wonder if anyone ever had this idea to work by?

Comment: have you actually checked that is allowed by the license agreement to package jboss to your client before going ahead with this?

Answer (score 2):

I would probably look into using something like [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/), instead of checking in all of JBoss.

Puppet uses a custom declarative language to define system configurations. Your puppet script would probably do the following:

- Download JBoss from a public server, and unzip it to your desired location
- Copy custom configuration files from your version control repo into JBoss
- Copy your applications into JBoss

Puppet is a lot more powerful than the simple scenario that I have just described, but this scenario is a start.

With this solution, you would only end up checking in your puppet script and any custom JBoss configuration files you might need. In addition, I believe it would make your JBoss upgrade path a lot simpler, as you would only need to change the version of JBoss in your puppet script, and re-run puppet.

Comment: suggests "something like Puppet"; things that are like puppet include [Chef](https://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home), [Ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible), [Salt](http://www.saltstack.com/community/), and a number of other but far less well-known tools. Of the options, i have only used Puppet, and while i can confirm that it is very powerful, it is also rather baroque and often a pain to work with. If i was starting from scratch, i would start with Ansible, which is built to be powerful but simple.

Comment: Thanks @TomAnderson. I was unfamiliar with Ansible. I completely agree with your description of Puppet. Since (I think) OP is just talking about a JBoss deployment, simple would definitely be better. Reserve Puppet for your 100-node Hadoop clusters.

Answer (score 1):

I think the ideal way to deal with situations like this is through [packaging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_management_system). If your client is deploying on some sort of unix server (i include Linux in that), then they are already using a package manager to manage system software on their servers. A package manager has the ability to install software, remove it, upgrade it, and, crucially for you, to install other packages on which some package depends.

You could therefore package JBoss, so that the package manager could install it, then package your application, specifying a dependency on JBoss. When the client installs your application package, JBoss will automatically be installed.

However, this plan only works if you client has a certain degree of infrastructure set up. They need to be using a system with a package manager. They need to have a way of managing package installation (a configuration management tool like Puppet, Chef, Ansible, or something vendor-proprietary is ideal for this). They need to be able to distribute custom packages inside their environment. They need to have either a way of accepting custom packages from you, or of accepting package build scripts and then building packages themselves.

In a server environment of any size, the sysadmins should and probably will have all this infrastructure anyway, because it's fundamental to managing a fleet of servers. But if your client doesn't have it, it may be too much effort to set up.

That said, the absolutely minimal version of this approach would be for you to send them the package files for the application and JBoss by email or SFTP or whatever, and then for the sysadmins to install them manually (eg with [`yum localinstall`](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/YumAndRPM#head-3c061f4a180e5bc90b7f599c4e0aebdb2d5fc7f6)). This is not a lot better than having them install JBoss manually, but it's a step in the right direction.